# jQuery & PHP: Upload an image and refresh gallery page with new thumbnail

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, upload

I have a page that contains thumbnails for a photo gallery. On this page is a link to upload more images. When you click the link a modal opens that contains an upload form (jquery colorbox in an iframe) which will allow you to upload one image (plus its name, caption, etc) at a time using PHP. When the form is submitted the image uploads and the page refreshes in the modal to allow for more uploads.

Since this modal is sitting on top of the existing thumbnails I'd really like for the user to see the new thumbnail added to the page after it's uploaded. Is this possible? How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the modal is in an `iframe`. If that's the case, when the upload is submitted, and the modal form reloads to allow for another upload, simply send the previously uploaded file info (thumbnail URL) back to the parent frame.  For example:

```
parent.uploadCallback('http://my.domain.com/newly-uploaded-thumbnail.jpg');
```

Then have a `uploadCallback` function in the main frame which creates an `img` object and appends it to your list of thumbnails.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a back-end guy - not very js proficient. Could you point me to an example? I wasn't able to find anything that matched what I'm trying to do.